# EF Core: Error cannot be modified an OwnsOne property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core to manage a SQL Server 2016 database (with code-first approach). In particular, i've a relation between 2 entities: Events and ObjectsForEvents.

These are the entities:

```
// Base entity: all entities extends this class
public class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

// Event entity: parent entity
public class EventEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public EventTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long StartAt { get; set; }
    public long EndAt { get; set; }
    public Guid? RecursiveCriteriaId { get; set; }
}

// Objects for events: child entity
public class ObjectForEventEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }
    public ObjectForEventPowerValue ElectricPowerValue { get; set; }
    public ObjectForEventPowerValue ThermalPowerValue { get; set; }
}
```

When i try insert many events with their objects, objects coming from the first event are inserted without problems. Trying to insert the objects for the second event, EF throws the following error:

```
The property 'ObjectForEventEntityId' on entity type 'ObjectForEventEntity.ElectricPowerValue#ObjectForEventPowerValue' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.
```

The `ElectricPowerValue` is based on this class:

```
public class ObjectForEventPowerValue
{
    public float Min { get; set; }
    public float Max { get; set; }
}
```

And is declared in the database context as follow:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectForEventEntity>(entity =>
{
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        entity.OwnsOne(e => e.ElectricPowerValue);
        entity.OwnsOne(e => e.ThermalPowerValue);
});
```

This is the part of code that insert the objects:

```
foreach (var addedEvent in addedEvents)
            {
                foreach (var obj in eventWithRecursiveCriteria.Objects)
                {
                    await this._objectsForEventService.Create(new ObjectForEventDto
                    {
                        EventId = addedEvent.Id,
                        ObjectId = obj.Id,
                        ElectricPowerValue = obj.ElectricPowerValue != null ? obj.ElectricPowerValue : new ObjectForEventPowerValue(),
                        ThermalPowerValue = obj.ThermalPowerValue != null ? obj.ThermalPowerValue : new ObjectForEventPowerValue()
                    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
                };
            }
```

Anyone can help me?

**UPDATE 1**
I've tried to change the key of the entity but still not works:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectForEventEntity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id });

                entity.OwnsOne(e => e.ElectricPowerValue);
                entity.OwnsOne(e => e.ThermalPowerValue);
            });
```

Comment: Try this pls entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id});

Comment: @PedroBrito please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that c# passes objects (not values) by reference. This means that in the insert, it tries to pass the `obj.ThermalPowerValue` as a reference instead of inserting a new value.

```
ElectricPowerValue = obj.ElectricPowerValue != null ? obj.ElectricPowerValue : new ObjectForEventPowerValue(),
ThermalPowerValue = obj.ThermalPowerValue != null ? obj.ThermalPowerValue : new ObjectForEventPowerValue()
```

You could try the following code:

```cs
foreach (var addedEvent in addedEvents)
            {
                foreach (var obj in eventWithRecursiveCriteria.Objects)
                {
                    await this._objectsForEventService.Create(new ObjectForEventDto
                    {
                        EventId = addedEvent.Id,
                        ObjectId = obj.Id,
                        ElectricPowerValue = obj.ElectricPowerValue != null ? new ObjectForEventPowerValue(){Min = obj.ElectricPowerValue.Min, Max = obj.ElectricPowerValue.Max} : new ObjectForEventPowerValue(),
                        ThermalPowerValue = obj.ThermalPowerValue != null ? new ObjectForEventPowerValue(){Min = obj.ThermalPowerValue.Min, Max = obj.ThermalPowerValue.Max} : new ObjectForEventPowerValue()
                    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
                };
            }
```